# look for differences between similarily named vectors (e.g. *_pre and *_post) in R

Tags: r

i have a dataframe with multiple columns that code an exposure (as 1/0) over multiple time points and follow a naming pattern, e.g. exposure1_pre2, exposure1_pre1, exposure1_post ... exposuren_pre2, ...

working example

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(exposure1_pre2 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = T),
             exposure1_pre1 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = T),
             exposure1_post = sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = T),
             exposure2_pre2 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = T),
             exposure2_pre1 = sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = T),
             exposure2_post = sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = T)
             )
```

i would like to code dummy variables that are set to 1/0 if there is a directional change from one time point to another, i.e. when exposure1_pre2 is 0 and exposure1_pre1 is 1 the new column exposure1_pre2_to_pre1 == 1.

i am trying to realize this with dplyr if_else - or ideally case_when for all possible combinations - and am thinking along the lines of

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(contains("pre2"),
    ~if_else(.x == 0 & ??? == 1, 1, 0), .names = "{???}_pre2_to_pre1")
  )
```

as is obvious, i am lost how to structure the condition so that it looks for the similarly named *_pre2 variable to assess for a difference and also would need to take only the exposure part from the input column for the naming of the new column - i suppose a grep could do here?

thank you very much and have a good day!

Comment: thats intentional but i agree confusing, i deleted the peri part - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Loop `across` the 'pre2' column, get the column name (`cur_column()`), replace the substring with 'pre1', `get` the value, do the compound logical expression and coerce the output logical to binary with `+` (or `as.integer`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
 df %>%
  mutate(
     across(contains("pre2"),
             ~ +(. == 0 & get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'pre2', 'pre1')) == 1),
              .names = '{.col}_to_pre1'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 8
   exposure1_pre2 exposure1_pre1 exposure1_post exposure2_pre2 exposure2_pre1 exposure2_post exposure1_pre2_to_pre1 exposure2_pre2_to_pre1
            <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>                  <int>                  <int>
 1              1              0              1              0              1              1                      0                      1
 2              1              0              1              1              0              0                      0                      0
 3              1              0              1              1              0              0                      0                      0
 4              1              1              1              0              1              0                      0                      1
 5              0              1              1              0              0              0                      1                      0
 6              1              1              1              0              1              1                      0                      1
 7              0              1              0              1              0              0                      1                      0
 8              0              1              0              1              1              1                      1                      0
 9              0              1              0              0              1              0                      1                      1
10              1              0              1              1              1              0                      0                      0
11              0              0              1              0              0              1                      0                      0
12              0              1              1              1              1              1                      1                      0
13              0              1              1              1              1              0                      1                      0
14              1              1              1              0              0              1                      0                      0
15              1              1              1              1              0              0                      0                      0
16              1              1              1              0              0              1                      0                      0
17              0              0              0              1              0              0                      0                      0
18              1              0              0              0              0              0                      0                      0
19              1              0              0              0              0              1                      0                      0
20              1              0              1              1              0              1                      0                      0
```